# gorm datetime null fetch wrong value

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm using gorm to get some data,but there is a behavior works not what I think.

entity(generate by gen):

```
type Test struct {
   ID   int32     `gorm:"column:id;primaryKey;autoIncrement:true" json:"id"`
   Time time.Time `gorm:"column:time" json:"time"`
}
```

data:

```
|  ID      | time                  |
| -------- | --------------------- |
| 1        | null                  |
| 2        | 2022-11-16 16:31:31   |
| 3        | null                  |
| 4        | null                  |
```

code:

```
var tests []entity.Test
orm.Find(&tests)
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", tests)
```

expecting:

```
   [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "time": "2022-11-16T16:31:31+08:00"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        }
    ],
```

what I get:

```
[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "time": "2022-11-16T16:31:31+08:00"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "time": "2022-11-16T16:31:31+08:00"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "time": "2022-11-16T16:31:31+08:00"
        }
    ]
```

When the TIME feild is null the value get coverd by previous one.

And I notice that when set the Time  feild to string I can get the right value.like this:

```
type Test struct {
    ID   int32
    Time string
    T    int32
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> When the TIME feild is null the value get coverd by previous one.

Please check this in the database that it is the same data that your program is reading; This should not happen for null values.

Suggestion: Please use [`sql.NullTime`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#NullTime) for such use cases, so that null values remain null in the database, `time.Time` will default to zero time for such columns when the entity is saved.

Comment: Thanks,`sql.NullTime` works fine, just like `string`.but I want to know the reason why`time.Time` behave like this..  I'm reading the source code,hope can get some clue.